# How to see error messages when running an exe compiled with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I would like to see the error message when executing an exe that I compiled with cx_Freeze, how can I do that?

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you downvote please leave a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: A question mark at the end does not make it a question.  Try:  "
I would like to see the error message when executing an `exe` that I compiled with cx_Freeze, how can I do that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the executable from the command line or powershell. The console won't close immediately that way, so if there are any error messages, you'll be able to read them

Comment: (+1) Minor point:  Many people now use Power Shell instead of Command Line.  You might want to include that (you have made quite a good answer though).